# NumPy array indexing a 4D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 4D array 'a' of size (2,3,4,4) filled with zeros.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((2,3,4,4))
```

I also have a 3D array 'b' of size(2,3,4) that carries some index values (all between 0 and 3).

What I want to do is replace the element of every last array in 'a' (the 4th dimension of 'a') that corresponds to the index in 'b', with 1.

I can do this with 3 for loops, as shown below:

```py
for i in a.shape[0]:
    for j in a.shape[1]:
        for z in a.shape[2]:
            a[i,j,z][b[i,j,z]] = 1
```

But I was wondering if there is anyway I can avoid looping at all. Something similar to:

```py
a[b] = 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can do this in a vectorized form:

```py
p,m,n,r = a.shape
a.reshape(-1,r)[np.arange(p*m*n),b.ravel()] = 1
```

This should generalize more easily to higher order ndarrays.